# How to manipulate java.util.Date date() from outside the java binary?

Tags: java, date, testing

I have a java app using date() to obtain the current date, and I'm trying to manipulate the date that it is obtaining from date() for testing purposes.

I've tried setting the system date(on Windows) to a date in the past for example 1/1/2014, but the java app seems to keep getting the realtime date from somewhere other than the system date.

Is it possible to manipulate the date and if so, how can I manipulate the date that the date() function returns from outside the binary?

Comment: Which implementation of java are you using?

Comment: @Natecat java version "1.7.0_80" JRE build 1.7.0_80-b15

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen, i've killed the processes after changing the date and restarting the java app but I still get "actual realtime date" rather than the 1/1/2014

Comment: have you looked into SimpleDateFormat SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");

Comment: First, make your device offline: no internet, no data connection... Then change the time on Windows, then reboot and change the time on bios. Then you are ready to go

Comment: Hmm..tell me the solution to workaround the licenses.

Comment: @LearningPhase changing the code isn't an option in this case. It's more of me trying to understand where date() get's the date from and how I can manipulate it from outside the binary...

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen thanks for the suggestion Tung, unfortunately I need to remote into the machine to work on it so I can't change those settings. Are we saying that the date() function takes the date from the BIOS rather than Windows system time?

Comment: Date gets its time from System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: It is completely system dependent, don't count on a specific implementation

Comment: @Natecat thanks for that clarification. Is there a way I can manipulate this from outside the binary?

Comment: If you're using an open source implementation of java like OpenJDK you could always see how they implemented that method in C and change wherever it is sourcing its time from.

Answer (score 2):

No need to manipulate from outside Java. Your tests within Java can alter the values reported as the current moment.

## java.time

You are using old outmoded classes. Those classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

You can override the abstract [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class to supply your own implementation. Your class can alter the date-time it reports as needed for your testing purposes.

The `Clock` class offers some static methods such as [`fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-), [`offset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#offset-java.time.Clock-java.time.Duration-), and [`tick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tick-java.time.Clock-java.time.Duration-) to conveniently provide altered Implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` class in `Java` uses the system time reported via System.currentTimeMillis(). This, in `Windows`, invokes the low resolution `Win32/64` API call `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`, which always returns "the current system date and time in UTC format", as per [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If there was access to the code and the requirement were to produce a custom `Date` object, representing some arbitrary time besides current, the recommended way would have been via the `Calendar` class.

For example:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); // 0 = January, 11 = December
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // 1 to 31
```

Given the above, a new `Date` object can be retrieved as follows:

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```